# Flutter - How to implement multiline underlined TextField

Tags: flutter

I want to implement the following Ui which contains a multiline TextField with underline below every single line. any idea on how I can implement this?

[image]

```
Expanded(
child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
    child: TextField(
        controller: problemItem.titleController,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        minLines: 3,
        maxLines: 100,
        )
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `Stack` to stack the `TextField` onto lines. You need to set the `expands` attribute of the `TextField` to true in order to make it expand to the full three-line width right from the start.
 I implemented a similar `TextField` to the one you are trying to create:

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 4 + (i + 1) * 28,
          left: 15,
          right: 15,
        ),
        height: 1,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    const SizedBox(
      height: 97,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
          cursorHeight: 22,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
          ),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          expands: true,
          maxLines: null,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**It is just a simple example of how to generate an underline when text change for a general case. The output behavior on the screen still needs to be tuned if the underline position is not on the place you want.**

Check more on [heigh](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html) property

[image]

If you want to allocate a Fixed Lines Textfield, you can try the below widget:

`style` is required because it uses the fontSize & height to calculate the line number

`controller` use to monitor the text changed

`textPainter` in the initState simulates the text behavior of the text and calculates the lines of text that will be shown.

```
class UnderlineTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const UnderlineTextField({
    required this.style,
    this.controller,
    this.maxLines = 3,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final int? maxLines;
  final TextStyle style;

  @override
  State<UnderlineTextField> createState() => _UnderlineTextFieldState();
}

class _UnderlineTextFieldState extends State<UnderlineTextField> {
  double maxWidth = 0;
  int numberOfLines = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    /// Calculate numberOfLines
    widget.controller?.addListener(() {
      final text = widget.controller?.text ?? '';
      final textPainter = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(text: text, style: widget.style),
        maxLines: widget.maxLines,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      );

      textPainter.layout(maxWidth: maxWidth);
      setState(() {
        numberOfLines = textPainter.computeLineMetrics().length;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fontSize = widget.style.fontSize ?? 12;
    final textHeight = fontSize * (widget.style.height ?? 1);

    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (_, constrinat) {
        maxWidth = constrinat.maxWidth;
        return Stack(
          children: [
            TextField(
              style: widget.style,
              controller: widget.controller,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                isDense: true,
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
              maxLines: widget.maxLines,
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: List.generate(
                  numberOfLines,
                  (index) => Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: textHeight - 1),
                      const Divider(height: 1, thickness: 1),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I would love some more explanation on this and maybe a full example of the UnderLineTextField widget

Comment: The original answer is posted a long time ago. I updated it and simplify the widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack(
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 4 + (i + 1) * 28,
                  left: 15,
                  right: 15,
                ),
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                expands: true,
                maxLines: null,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).